# How to make matplotlib's sequential colormaps "pop" more?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use `matplotlib`'s single-color colormaps (e.g. `Blues`), but I want the color to "pop" more. I'm not sure what the technical term is for this - higher contrast, increased brightness, something else.

My question: how, in `matplotlib`, can I make a single-color colormap more vibrant?

There's a toy script and output below. In the output, I want both blue and red to be less dull.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

num_units_per_rf = 1000

# Emulate Gaussian DF
gaussian_place_cell_rf_list = []
gaussian_score_90_by_neuron_list = []
for place_cell_rf in np.arange(start=1, stop=4, step=0.5):
    score_90_by_neuron = np.random.normal(loc=place_cell_rf, size=num_units_per_rf)
    gaussian_score_90_by_neuron_list.append(score_90_by_neuron)
    gaussian_place_cell_rf_list.append(np.full(fill_value=place_cell_rf, shape=num_units_per_rf))
gaussian_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'place_cell_rf': np.concatenate(gaussian_place_cell_rf_list),
    'score_90_by_neuron': np.concatenate(gaussian_score_90_by_neuron_list),
})


noise_place_cell_rf_list = []
noise_score_90_by_neuron_list = []
for place_cell_rf in np.arange(start=1, stop=4, step=0.5):
    score_90_by_neuron = np.random.normal(loc=-place_cell_rf, size=num_units_per_rf)
    noise_score_90_by_neuron_list.append(score_90_by_neuron)
    noise_place_cell_rf_list.append(np.full(fill_value=place_cell_rf, shape=num_units_per_rf))
noise_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'place_cell_rf': np.concatenate(noise_place_cell_rf_list),
    'score_90_by_neuron': np.concatenate(noise_score_90_by_neuron_list),
})



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

# Plot Gaussians and Noise.
g = sns.kdeplot(
    data=gaussian_df,
    x='score_90_by_neuron',
    common_norm=False,  # Ensure each sweep is normalized separately.
    cumulative=True,
    hue='place_cell_rf',
    palette='Reds',
    ax=ax)

sns.kdeplot(
    data=noise_df,
    x='score_90_by_neuron',
    common_norm=False,  # Ensure each sweep is normalized separately.
    cumulative=True,
    hue='place_cell_rf',
    palette='Blues',
    ax=g)


plt.show()
```

[image]

I want the blues to "glow" more, like this subset of the `hsv` colormap:

[image]

I want the reds to "glow" more, like this subset of the `hsv` colormap:

[image]

Comment: you can use `vmin` and `vmax` to increase brightness and contrast of a colormap, when calling the `kdeplot`-function

Comment: How so? Could you add or link an example or documentation?

Comment: [Link1](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html) and [Link2](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html)

Comment: Another option would be to define a list with your own colors, create a colormap with `colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()` and then use this custom colormap in the `palette` argument in `kdeplot()`. You can directly customize the colors how you want them then

Comment: The first of the above links appear explain how to change the mapping from numeric values to values on the colormap. That's not quite what I want. I want to change the colors to have higher *lightness*. I want the colors themselves to change, not to "zoom in" on a subset of the palette

Comment: In other words, I don't think `vmin` and `vmax` can do what I want done.

Comment: If you create your own `Corlormap` you can multiply the RGB values by e.g. `1.5` or another constant to make it more vibrant

Comment: But if you want a higher lightness, wont all the colors fade away, because you are going towards white? Or am I just confused by your term lightness. Do you mean it like going from 50% transparent to 0% transparent and all the colors 'glow up'?

Comment: To be clear, I don't know the right term (brightness, lightness). "Glow" sounds plausible. I want something like a sequential colormap for `Blue`, but in the "style" of matplotlib's hsv blue subset https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#cyclic. I'll put an example in the original post.

Comment: The `Blues` and `Reds` feel "dusty". I want them more vibrant / neon